# Signal encoding identification

Tags: signal-analysis, demodulation

I've read this signal from a radio remote that opens a gate. This signal is already after AM demodulation, read by using a Saleae logic analyzer:

[image: signal screenshot]

I don't know much about signal processing, but I would like to emit the same signal with my own transmitter. To do this I would like to know what encoding this signal is using? Is it possible to determine the encoding type only by looking at the signal?

The spikes at the left is the beginning of the signal. I've truncated the rest of the signal because I guess there's no point in showing all of it.

Also could anyone guide me to some good resources about self-clocking signals, usage of low duty cycle clocks in signals, that would help me to decode the message in this signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This signal is already after AM demodulation

That means this is only meaningful if the signal actually only contains information in its amplitude; luckily, most simple remotes just use some form of On-Off-Keying or Pulse Position Modulation.

> Is it possible to determine the encoding type only by looking at the signal?

If this really is just a signal that is either on or off, then this looks like on-off keying. But really, your visualization might have hidden a lot of relevant information.

This might be a lot. It might simply be that the receiver uses the clock it has, or derives its clock from the preamble. Then, it could just be on/off, or it could also be manchester encoded.